# Repeatable-read transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, repeatable-read

Table `R (A)` containing the records `[(3), (4), (5)]` and transactions `T1` = `UPDATE R SET A = A * 2; INSERT INTO A VALUES (6);` and T2 = `'SELECT AVG (A) FROM R; SELECT AVG (A) FROM R'`
Knowing that transaction `T2` is executed using repeatable-read which are the posible values ​​returned by the second select?

I think that possible values are: `4` and `7.5`? Am I right? Please let me know if I correctly understand repeatable-read.

Comment: If by *repeatable-read* you mean once before the update and once after then 4 and 7.5 is correct.

Comment: Why integer? @forpas

Comment: What is the data type of the column A?

Comment: It's not specifed in the question

Comment: No it's 7.5. Now I saw that you tagged Oracle.  The data type is number something. So the result is a real number.

Comment: What's the timing of the individual statements, and when are the UPDATE statements committed?

Comment: Do you really mean `values ​​returned by the second select?` Or maybe do you rather mean  `values ​​returned by the second TRANSACTION`? In the first case - yes - either 4 or 7.5. In the second case - two selects return a pair of values, either 4+4  or  7.5+7.5 (other combinations are not possible like 4+7.5 or 7.5+4)